# AWS Codedeploy error "Could not download bundle at 'https://api.github.com/repos "

Tags: bitbucket, amazon-web-services, travis, travis-ci

Мне нужно сделать чтоб у меня код с bitbucket тестился на travis ci, и после удачного теста деплоился на AWS ЕС2, с помощью Codedeploy. Но когда тесты успешно пройдены, у меня в консоли AWS Codedeploy появляеться ошибка "Could not download bundle at 'https://api.github.com/repos/ ... ' after 3 retries. Server returned codes: 404 'Not Found'; 404 'Not Found'; 404 'Not Found'; 404 'Not Found'.". Думаю, она связана с тем что у меня закрытый репозиторий на Bitbucket, но не знаю как пофиксить.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Духсообщества мне нужно чтоб код деплоился на AWS ЕС2 после успешных тестов в travis-ci. В качестве среды для системы контроля версий я использую Bitbucket, и у меня закрытый репозиторий. Я уже настроил travis, тесты запускаются и успешно проходят, так же после тестов запускается деплой через AWS Codedeploy. Но в процесе самого деплоя появляестя ошыбка в консоли AWS, которую я указывал выше. (На сервере ЕС2 я поставил codedeploy agent). Короче говоря, на процесе деплоя почему-то AWS не может взять код с Bitbucket.

Comment: а если у вас код находится в `bitbucket` почему вы настроили codedeploy на код с `github`?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten api по которой делался запрос, и возникла ошибка, создалась сама автоматически, я не настаивал ее на этапе деплоя. А от travis брал код для тестов верно и все работает коректно с тревисом